# Can't get Azure TableEntity etag on CreateQuery

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm doing a query for entities from a table, changing them, then doing a replace operation.
The replace operation fails because the etag property on the etag is null.  I checked, and the etag is null when I get the entity from a CreateQuery() call, but populated when I do Retrieve().  Is there a way to get the etag manually?

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> query = from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(tableName)
                                        where e.Id == queryId
                                        select e;

MyEntity entity = query.FirstOrDefault();

// Update the MyEntity object

var replaceOperation = TableOperation.Replace(entity);
MyCloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName).Execute(replaceOperation);

// Exception is thrown here that eTag value is null
```

Comment: Have you considered just setting the entity's ETag to "*" (asterisk) before calling Replace? Unless you have specific requirements that you haven't mentioned, then you can just tell the table operation to ignore the ETag by setting it to asterisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that you are mixing two different components.

```
serviceContext.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(tableName)
```

is using the System.Data.Services.Client namespace.  In this model the entity itself does not track the etag, the context does this for you.

```
MyCloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName).Execute(replaceOperation)
```

Is using the Table.DataServices namespace.  In this model there is no central context and each entity tracks its own state by exposing an Etag property. This is enforced via the ITableEntity interface. The entity you are using from  the query is not intended to be used with the newer libraries, and this is the root of the problem.

Switch to using

```
MyCloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName).CreateQuery<MyEntity>()
```

to create your query and your issues should go away.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using TableQuery instead of DataServiceQuery?

So..

cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(TableName).CreateQuery()
instead of serviceContext.CreateQuery..‏

btw TableQuery is new in 2.1 I think...